# Code signing "StreamAlpha.bundle" failed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

This Version 9.2 (9C40b) on Mac High Sierra 0.13.2 (17C88) error seems to be new with no search engine results..

[image]

Here are the logs: IDEDistribution.standard.log

```
2018-01-07 05:15:37 +0000  Platform to submission preferences result after merging and ingestion: {
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7d20170:'com.apple.platform.watchos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7d20100:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9da32350: storeMC: 3, storeBC: 2, devBC: YES, storeODR: 0>";
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7eb5b40:'com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7eb5ac0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9c654c40: storeMC: 2, storeBC: 0, devBC: YES, storeODR: 1>";
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7d23d00:'com.apple.platform.macosx':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7d23c90:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9c683560: storeMC: 2, storeBC: 0, devBC: YES, storeODR: 0>";
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7eb25b0:'com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7eb2530:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9c6b5810: storeMC: 1, storeBC: 0, devBC: YES, storeODR: 1>";
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7c72c90:'com.apple.platform.watchsimulator':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7c46bb0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9c78d020: storeMC: 1, storeBC: 0, devBC: YES, storeODR: 1>";
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7d727a0:'com.apple.platform.appletvos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7d72de0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9d718220: storeMC: 3, storeBC: 2, devBC: YES, storeODR: 1>";
"<DVTPlatform:0x7ffca7daa920:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ffca7d76140:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>" = "<IDEAppSubmissionPreference: 0x7ffc9c649dd0: storeMC: 3, storeBC: 1, devBC: YES, storeODR: 1>";
```

snippet shown above, see full one here

https://pastebin.com/tTT3fJKp

IDEDistribution.verbose.log

https://pastebin.com/g5mnDq6L

IDEDistributionPipeline

https://pastebin.com/d0KUSK1R

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it seems like you have set the distribution provisioning to Automatic. While its not taking it automatically or not fully configured.

Here are some steps which help you to sort out issue :

> - Firstly download again distribution from developer account & re install it on Xcode by double tapping on it
> - Now uncheck automatic provisioning & do set up it manually by selecting provisioning
> - Do the same process in Targets -> Build Settings as well
> - Clean the project & remove derived data
> - Change the build no & create new archive file & try upload it

Hope it will help you....